# what if run 2 type-2 VMX hypervisors in one x86 host?

Tags: linux, windows, x86, virtualization

In Intel VMX operation, firstly, it needs to call `VMXON(VMXON_REGION)` to enable VMX in the CPU, and then `VMPTRLD(VMCS_REGION)`, etc.
Here comes my question.
What if two hosted hypervisors are running at the same time in one X86 host?
The first VMXON goes well, but second VMXON will go fail.
And 2 hypervisors may call `VMPTRLD(VMCS_REGION_a)`, and `VMPTRLD(VMCS_REGION_b)`, the current VMCS in the CPU is changed, will it crash the other hypervisor or they can co-exist with each other?
From my SDM reading, I don't think they can co-exist, maybe i again missed something important.

Please help clarifying on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, current state of Intel VT-x does not allow concurrent operation of two independent virtual machine monitors (VMM) side by side. They will create a conflict of system resources that will lead to undefined behavior, including crashes of virtual machines (VM), hangs or reboots, maybe data corruption.

As an example, it is unsafe to load kernel drivers for different visualization solutions at the same time, not even starting VMs. I've experienced problems when e.g. KVM and Virtualbox or KVM and Simics VMP were loaded together.

It is impossible for one VMM to safely block loading or operation of another one.
It is even problematic for one VMM to reliably detect presence of other VMMs, as VMXON/VMXOFF can be done dynamically during operating system (OS) operation, and there is no hardware resource that could act as a mutually exclusive object or a lock for virtualization resources.

The only approach that will work with modern hardware is for a host OS to provide an API for mediating requests to underlying virtualization resources (VMXON/VMXOFF, VMPTRLD, VMLAUNCH/VMRESUME etc.) and for all VMMs to agree on using this API. Such facilities exist for Apple Mac OS X and since recently for Microsoft Windows systems. However, one can argue that these APIs are somewhat limiting a VMM author.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense. As you said, the co-existing VMMs may be crashed or undefined behaves. I would like to validate this by running KVM, and VBX or Simics in one hosts.